# OneToOne Joined column issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having issue with @OneToOne unidirectional mapping. Parent PK is not getting saved on child joined column. e.g. invoice_master_id_pay of customer_payment should be inserted with customer_invoice_master of CustomerInvoiceMaster.

Here is the mapping.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_invoice_master")
public class CustomerInvoiceMaster {

@Id
private int invoiceMasterId;

// invoice_master_id_pay should be populated with 
// CustomerInvoiceMaster customer_invoice_master PK. This is not
// not happening. Row is created with zero value 
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "invoice_master_id_pay")
private CustomerPayment customerPayment;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="customer_payment")
public class CustomerPayment{
    @Id
    private int customerPaymentId; 

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you shown won't store parent `CustomerInvoiceMaster` PK on `invoice_master_id_pay`, it is the opposite, this one-to-one mapping will store `customerPaymentId` on `invoice_master_id_pay`.

The parent is who reference the child using join column.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was thinking short while ago. I concur with your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomerPayment cp=new CustomerPayment();
// assign properties to cp;
CustomerInvoiceMaster cim=new CustomerInvoiceMaster();
// assign properties to cti (including cp);
...
session.save(cim);   // would save both cp,cim;
```

If you want `session.save(cp);` to save both cp,cim use `OneToOne` bidirectional association.